# Automatticly instantiate PHP class with JavaScript HTTP request

Tags: javascript, php, oop

I'm using this (standard) JavaScript function to call up a PHP file and send data to it:

```
/**
 * The PHP file which receives the data
 *
 * @type {string} The php filename
 */
const INSTALL_FILE = "install.php";

/**
 * Passes roadTaxData to the php install file which could be get with the $_POST operator
 */
function passToPHP (paramName, data) {
    var httpc = new XMLHttpRequest(); // simplified for clarity"
    httpc.open("POST", INSTALL_FILE, true); // sending as POST

    httpc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    /*
     Test purposes
     */
    httpc.onreadystatechange = function () { //Call a function when the state changes.
        if (httpc.readyState == 4 && httpc.status == 200) { // complete and no errors
            console.log(httpc.responseText); // some processing here, or whatever you want to do with the response
        }
    };
    httpc.send(paramName + "=" + data);
}
```

In my PHP file i'm using this code:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');

$road_tax_data = json_decode($_POST['road-tax_data'], true);

return new RoadTaxDataParser($road_tax_data);
```

Is there any way to automaticly instantiate that `RoadTaxDataParser` class?

Comment: What makes you think PHP does not automatically create an instance of the `RoadTaxDataParser` class?

Comment: @Bjorn There's a file between. The `install.php` and the file where the class is in.

Comment: @Bjorn as I understand OPs Question, he wants to **omit** the `return new RoadTaxDataParser($road_tax_data);` and having a kind of auto-loading by request.

Comment: I can't figure out what you have in mind but you simply cannot send a PHP object across the wire and use it from JavaScript. Your script must print something that JavaScript can parse (possibly JSON).

Comment: @AxelAmthor Exactly.

Comment: are you trying to return the object created by `return new RoadTaxDataParser($road_tax_data);` because what you'l get is the value returned by __construct() in `RoadTaxDataParser` class

Comment: @Bjorn It's not about class autoloading. OP wants the class to be **instantiated** automatically on a request coming in w/o doing this explicitly by calling "`new ClassName()`". This is not applicable IMHO. And not recommended securitywise.

Comment: @Bjorn No i mean that i can directly instantiate the `RoadTaxDataParser` class from the `passToPHP` method. with no php file which it instantiates.

Comment: If you want that, you should port the RoadTaxDataParser to Javascript (I have no idea what the class produces and/or what data it uses though). As Alvaro said, it's simply impossible to send PHP objects to Javascript and reuse them.

Comment: @Bjorn What do you mean by porting the class?

Comment: It simply means you have to rebuild it in Javascript (and you do not need the original PHP class anymore).

Comment: Oow, no.. That's not really an option. I think i'd go with the answer below then from just instantiating the class from another file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may implement some more generic "`index.php`" which auto-instantiates classes which inherit from a certain abstract class or implement an interface i.e.

Then you may pass the requested class name either as an argument or as a path.

But this will not be totally generic and not automatically, it will just be able to do your application.

And you have to take care about a lot of security concerns to prevent people from loading and instantiating arbitrary (harmfull) classes.

This concept may lean to the "servlet" idea in JSP, which you are probably looking for in PHP.